# date picker cannot show using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

why date picker don't show..i want date picker show in 2 form because it have date start and date end..........
thanks for helping......

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
};
</script>
<form action="index.php?page=form" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Date Start
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="date1" id="inputField">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Date Finish
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="date2" id="inputField">
    </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: major flaw: `id` values must be unique in each html document. You've got two identical IDs. Beyond that, have you done any debugging yourself? Did you check your javascript console for errors?

Comment: javascript don have problem..because i download from internet... can you give me some example to show all date picker in that form

Comment: yes, and everything on the internet is completely true and useable...

Comment: suggestion is to have different IDs for your Input tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });

    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField2",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
};
</script>
<form action="index.php?page=form" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Date Start
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="date1" id="inputField">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Date Finish
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="date2" id="inputField2">
    </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique and you should assign different IDs for your input fields. Also wrap your code inside `$(document).ready( function()` like;

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  new JsDatePick({
    useMode:2,
    target:"inputField",
    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
  });
  new JsDatePick({
    useMode:2,
    target:"inputField2",
    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
  });
});
```

*Note: I have not tested this.*